# I want to save all the values in the drop down in a list in .cs file

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a dropdown box where it has some values and I have a list in .cs file, I want to save all the values in the dropdown list to the list. 
ex:

list =

```
public list<int> UserId{get; set;}
```

Drop down =

```
<select>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
</select>
```

my code is like

URModel:

```
public List<int> UserId { get; set; }
```

cshtml:

```
<select multiple asp-for="URModel.UserId" name="list2" id="list2" size="8" style="float:right">
<option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you require to read the data from your file in the dropdown or vice versa?

Comment: vice versa, I want the data from the dropdown list to my file

Comment: And you suppose to do this for some GET/POST hit on some button click?

Comment: Ya on post I need to get that.

Comment: Can you please share your Controller and the complete post code.